# Generate TextBlock From codebehind in a particular

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, code-behind, textblock

Let say I have a `grid`,

```
<Grid Name="grid1">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Name="col1" Width="auto">
                                </ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Name="col2" Width="380">
                                </ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Name="col3" Width="auto">
                                </ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Name="col4" Width="200">
                                </ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinition>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Name="row1" Height="2*">
                                </RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Name="row2" Height="2*">
                                </RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>   
 <Grid>
```

That is `2` rows and `4` columns. I need to create a `TextBlock` in `Grid.Row="1"` and `Grid.Column="2"` from my code behind.

How can I create it in corresponding `Grid` *row* and *column* and set binding as

```
  myTextBlock1.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, (new Binding("SelectedItem." + dataGrid1.Columns[5].Header) 
     { ElementName = "dataGrid1" }));
```

to that `textblock` in run-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This :

```
    TextBlock MyTextBlock = New TextBlock();
    Grid.SetRow( MyTextBlock, 1 );
    Grid.SetColumn( MyTextBlock, 2 );
    grid1.Children.Add( MyTextBlock );
```